# Aggregate function ARRAY_AGG not allowed in SQL function

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

I have been trying to make a UDF in BigQuery to compress multiple rows into a single row

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_name(to_compress_column INT64, order_by_column INT64) AS (
    TO_JSON_STRING(
           ARRAY_AGG(
                IFNULL(to_compress_column,-1) RESPECT NULLS
                ORDER BY order_by_column
                    )
                  )
    );
```

But this causes the error "ARRAY_AGG not allowed in SQL function body". I tried using SELECT and UNNEST but since my input is not an ARRAY, it did not work.
How should I proceed?

Edit:

My input tables have this format:

| visits | place_id | date | hour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | abc123 | 2022-01-01 | 4 |
| 20 | abc123 | 2022-01-01 | 2 |
| 19 | abc123 | 2022-01-01 | 3 |
| 24 | abc123 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 26 | abc123 | 2022-01-01 | 5 |
| 18 | abc456 | 2022-01-01 | 2 |
| 20 | abc456 | 2022-01-01 | 3 |
| 17 | abc456 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |

I want my output tables to have this format:

| visits | place_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [24,20,19,23,26] | abc123 | 2022-01-01 |
| [17,18,20] | abc456 | 2022-01-01 |

I understand that I can do this by

```
SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(IFNULL(visits,-1) RESPECT NULLS
  ORDER BY hour)) visits, 
  place_id, 
  date 
  from input_table
  group by place_id, date
```

But in order to avoid repetition of the first line of the select query as there a lot of tables I have to do this in, I want to create a UDF so that the query changes to:

```
SELECT function_name(visits,hour) visits, 
      place_id, 
      date 
      from input_table
      group by place_id, date
```

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) - I think yo are in that trap

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I see, I have edited my question to add perspective on what I am trying to achieve through the function approach

Comment: what you want is actually called aggregate UDF and BigQuery does not support such (at least yet)! so udf direction looks like dead end here . will think more on this ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you want is actually called aggregate UDF and BigQuery does not support such (at least yet)! so aggregate udf direction looks like dead end here

What I see as an option is described in below example

```
create temp function func_name (arr any type) as (( 
  select to_json_string(array_agg(ifnull(visits,-1) respect nulls order by hour))
  from unnest(arr) 
));
select func_name(array_agg(struct(visits, hour))) visits, 
  place_id, 
  date 
  from input_table
  group by place_id, date
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

So, it is not 100% of what you wanted , but very close in my mind
So, instead of desired line

```
function_name(visits,hour) visits,
```

you will have to use

```
function_name(array_agg(struct(visits, hour))) visits,
```

I feel like this is reasonable trade-off :o)

P.S. And, obviously, instead of temp function you will create permanent function ...